# Javascript regex to find everything except text inside html tags, and exclude some tags

Tags: javascript, regex

I've been trying to create a javascript regex to find everything in an HTML page that is content, this excludes any texts inside html tags or properties like:

```
<div this_shouldnt_match>this should match</div>
```

I also want to exclude any text inside span tags.

The Regex I have so far is:

```
var reg = "(?<!<[^>]*)" + this.searchString;
```

This successfully matches text outside tags, but does not exclude text between span tags. Can anyone help out?

Comment: Are you sure [you want to extract the content via regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)? Why don't you parse the HTML instead?

Comment: Please take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/5066625

Comment: In general using regular expressions to parse HTML is not a good idea,  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: This question has been asked many times. For accurate results, you must not parse the HTML with regular expressions. Voting to close this as duplicate.